# Transiting at Montreal airport to other Quebec airports - will I be quarantined in Montreal or at my destination?

Tags: canada, covid-19, quarantine, quebec

I'm a european citizen going to Canada for work. My destination is in Quebec, but there's no direct flight from my city to the destination, i.e. I have to change flight at Montreal airport.

I know I will be quarantined for 2 weeks, but will I be quarantined at Montreal -1st place I reach in Canada), or can I take a second intern flight and quarantine myself at my destination?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can quarantine at your final destination.

> If you are cleared to fly, you may board a connecting flight to reach your final destination. You do not need to quarantine (self-isolate) before connecting, unless your final destination requires you to quarantine at a designated location first.
>
> https://travel.gc.ca/travel-covid/travel-restrictions/provinces#connecting

However, like any traveller, if you start showing symptoms during your layover, you will not be allowed to board the connecting flight without public health approval.